# Plot triangles in real-time

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, data-visualization, visualization

I'm trying to implement an algorithm with python. I completed it but now I need some visualizing at runtime for tracking the value changes.

In a nutshell my algorithm creates different 3 points in every step. In 2D we can represent a triangle with this 3 point. So I need draw triangles which created in current step on loop to the coordinate system. My points are like: `[2,4] x=2, y=4`. My triangle simplex values are like for a step: `[[0.2, 4.2], [2.798, 2.7], [0.2, 1.2]]`

I tried various libs and codes for this. I don't want to write useless codes that I tried. And also generally plot libraries(like `matplotlib`) draws shapes at the end of program as output. But I need to see them at the real-time. Do you have any advice or an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `pause()` after `draw()` like this:

```
plt.draw()
plt.pause(0.1)
```

You can also save it to a file if you need it for later:

```
plt.savefig("yourFile")
```